# Replacing an ActionBar menu item icon with an indeterminate ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I would like to add an indeterminate progress bar to the Honeycomb ActionBar, so that any time the user presses "Refresh", the refresh icon temporarily turns into an indeterminate progress bar, until the task completes. The Email app does this already, but I can't figure out how.

Any advice?

Comment: Related for refresh/refreshing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly how the Email app does it, but you may want to stay simple and just call [setIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setIcon%28int%29) with the id of a `StateDrawable` XML file, and then just change the state using a Timer.

Comment: Set icon is only possible for a tab Icon and not for the Actionbar itself. Is this working by accident also for ActionIcons or is this answer wrong?

Answer (score 19):

To clarify Jon O's answer, the key is to set and unset an action view on the refresh action. This works in both ActionBarSherlock and native 4.x action bar.  The following snippet will put the progress indeterminate view on top of the refresh icon, assuming the refresh menu item has ID 'refresh_option' and the replacement layout (which has a ProgressBar) is in layout 'progress_wheel':

```
 MenuItem item = abmenu.findItem(R.id.refresh_option);
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View abprogress = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_wheel, null);
 item.setActionView(abprogress);
```

Unset the progress view, and the refresh icon will return to visibility:

```
 item.setActionView(null);
```

See [a more detailed example](https://github.com/larham/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/app/ActionBarRefreshProgress.java) on github.

Comment: The problem is: new ProgressBar is a bit wider than regular action item. Thus all neighboring items shift to the sides a bit whne it appears (and "jumb back" when it disappears). Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Anyone else seeing what I am seeing in AndroidX, where setActionView() (to either a View or a layout) just makes actionbar MenuItems disappear??

Answer (score 5):

To simplify [larham1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329561/885028): you don't even need to inflate new action view itself because `MenuItem` has [the method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int)) which accepts id of action layout, so you can simply write:

```
item.setActionView(R.layout.progress_bar);
```

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Google has posted an example of doing exactly this as a part of their broader ActionBarCompat compatibility project.  [Have a look](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html).

Comment: That example relies on a set layout with adjacent refresh icon and indeterminate progress, using show/hide.  In the ActionBar, we don't have that layout nor access.  Trying Femi's idea next...

Comment: It does use show/hide on older devices, yes; however, if you look in the ActionBarHelperHoneycomb/ActionBarHelperICS classes, they do it the proper/updated way for ICS and Honeycomb too.  It works on all devices (I know; I'm leveraging it in my own app for 2.1+, 3.x, and 4.x and it works on all of them, indeterminate progress bar included.)

Comment: Link is now broken (Google decided to delete the URL? Sigh)

Comment: Unfortunately.  But I think you can still get the code from the SDK examples for the android support libraries.  Or google "actionbarcompat" and peek into one of the many github repositories that contain it in some form (I'm hesitant to link any one in particular).

Comment: How can you replace the menu item button/icon with the indeterminate progressbar using the broadcast intents? ive tried this but keep failing.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do it by:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh: 
                item.setActionView(new ProgressBar(this));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: The problem is: new ProgressBar is a bit wider than regular action item. Thus all neighboring items shift to the sides a bit whne it appears (and "jumb back" when it disappears). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I created a layout file with the ```<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:padding="4dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 />```. It avoids shifting of menu items. Remember to set the ```item.setActionView(R.layout.your_layout);```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the code provided at the original issue here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/425

Except for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` (in the actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml) I use `32dp`; as this was the way it was done in ActionBarCompat:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/res/layout-v11/actionbar_indeterminate_progress.html