# Replace Icon with ProgressBar

Tags: android, replace, icons, android-progressbar

I want there to be an icon, which when clicked on, will be replaced by a spinning progress bar. Once the appropriate task in the background has finished, the `ProgressBar` should be replaced by the icon again.

This is similar to the progress bar we all are used to in the action bar (e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142722/replacing-an-actionbar-menu-item-icon-with-an-indeterminate-progressbar)), but I want to achieve the same thing within a `Fragment` (dialog), so [setActionView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29) is not available.

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: use an ImageButton with a custom Drawable set by setImageDrawable

Comment: @pskink Could you please elaborate a little bit on this? Would it be possible to somehow use the `Drawable` used by the `ProgressBar`?

Comment: yes, but its tricky, you can copy std progress_medium.xml to your drawable folder

Comment: So, there is no way to get a reference to the `Drawable` object used by `ProgressBar` internally? Copying a resource and reimplementing the Drawable seems to be redundant and leaves me at risk to get inconsistent whenever they decide to change the animation upstream :(.

Comment: good question, but yes, why not, you can do that, let me try

Comment: oh its too tricky, so better use a ViewSwitcher with two children: ImageButton and ProgressBar

Comment: `ViewSwitcher` seems to be the way to go. Will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So your next stop is [ProgressButton](https://github.com/SundeepK/ProgressButton) by [SundeepK](https://github.com/SundeepK) (MIT License)

> **ProgressButton** can be used to display a simple rotating Drawable to give the user 
>   the effect of a loading button. The Drawable will be displayed once the user clicks the button and will have to be manually dismissed using the **stopLoadingAnimation()** method.

ProgressButton class:

```
public class ProgressButton extends ImageButton {

private boolean _shouldDisplayLoadingAnimation = false;
private Drawable _loadingAnimation;
private TextPaint _textPaint;
private Rect _textBounds;
private String _defaultText;

public ProgressButton(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs_, int defStyle_) {
    super(context_, attrs_, defStyle_); 

    final TypedArray a = context_.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs_, R.styleable.ProgressButton,
            R.attr.progressButtonStyle, R.style.ProgressButton_attrs);

    this.setBackgroundColor(a.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressButton_defaultBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE));

    _loadingAnimation = getDrawable();
    _loadingAnimation.setAlpha(0);
    _defaultText = a.getString(R.styleable.ProgressButton_defaultText);
    _textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    _textPaint.density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    _textPaint.setColor(a.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressButton_defaultFontColor, Color.BLACK));
    _textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    _textPaint.setTextSize(a.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressButton_defaultFontSize, 40));
    _textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    _textBounds = new Rect();

    a.recycle();
}

public ProgressButton(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs_) {
    this(context_, attrs_, 0);
}

public ProgressButton(Context context_) {
    this(context_, null);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    boolean isClicked = super.performClick();
    if (isClicked) {
        _shouldDisplayLoadingAnimation = true;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    return isClicked;
};


public void startLoadingAnimation() {
    _shouldDisplayLoadingAnimation = true;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void stopLoadingAnimation() {
    _shouldDisplayLoadingAnimation = false;
    this.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas_) {
    if (_shouldDisplayLoadingAnimation) {
            shouldShowAnimation(true);
    } else {
        _textPaint.getTextBounds(_defaultText, 0, _defaultText.length(), _textBounds);
        canvas_.drawText( _defaultText , getWidth()/2, (getHeight()/2)+((_textBounds.bottom-_textBounds.top)/2) , _textPaint);
        shouldShowAnimation(false);
        _loadingAnimation.setVisible(false, false);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas_);

}

private void shouldShowAnimation(boolean shouldShow_) {
    if (_loadingAnimation instanceof Animatable) {
        if (shouldShow_) {
            _loadingAnimation.setAlpha(255);
            ((Animatable) _loadingAnimation).start();
        } else {
            _loadingAnimation.setAlpha(0);
            ((Animatable) _loadingAnimation).stop();
        }
    }
}
}
```

define ProgressButton in your layout:

```
<com.sun.progressbutton.ProgressButton
    android:id="@+id/progressView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/progress_view"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Seems to look quite promising, although I would like to solve this without pulling in dependencies, if possible. I'm not the one having downvoted your answer and I feel kind of bad about this, because your answer is definitely not bad!

Comment: @KarolBabioch about pulling in a dependency: anyway it's a single class. Just pull it in plus attributes in *attrs.xlm*. And possibly give credits in your *about* section.

Comment: Actually I've upvoted your answer (from -2 to -1) and have marked it as accepted answer now. However it wasn't me who voted you down in the first place. The question itself was also downvoted by the way :(.